# nvd3 multiBarChart with line along x axis

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I need to add a line with multiple values along the x axis of a multiBarChart. I cannot use another nvd3 control like multiChart or linePlusBarChart due to existing functionality breaking if i switch.

The following code and fiddle show what i have so far.

```
var limits = [[60,166990904656],[300,154990904656],[500,142990904656]];

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
    .y(function(d) { 
     d = d[1] / 1000000000;
     return d      
}).interpolate('step-after');

//The line SVG Path we draw
d3.select("#chart svg")
   .append("path")
   .attr("d", lineFunction(limits))
   .attr("stroke", "red")
   .attr("stroke-width", 1)
   .attr("fill", "none");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s2vemzht/11/

I am facing 3 issues: First is the x axis placement of the line. At the moment i have hardcoded this value into the limits array because i am unsure how to position it dynamically based on where the next bar starts.

The second issue is the limit value in relation to the other values in the data array. It does not seem accurately positioned.

The third issue is with the line not drawing over the 3rd bar even though there are 3 values in the limits array. I tried changing the interpolate property but it's still an issue.

I am a beginner with D3 so apologies for all the questions :-)

Comment: 1) `chart.height` can't be the same as `height`, otherwise your x axis will be cut off

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The x axis does not seem to be getting cut off at the moment.

Comment: Can you give the screenshot of what exactly you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out by drawing lines over the bars at particular points and positioning based on the y and x axis scales

```
          var yValueScale = chart.yAxis.scale(),
              yValue = 0,
              xValueScale = chart.xAxis.scale(),
              g = d3.select("#chart svg .nvd3");

        for(var i=0;i<limits.length;i++){
        g.append("line")
          .attr("class","limit-line")
          .attr("x1", xValueScale(d3.time.format('%b-%d')(new Date(limits[i][0]))))
          .attr("y1", yValueScale(limits[i][1]/ 1000000000))
          .attr("x2", xValueScale(d3.time.format('%b-%d')(new Date(limits[i][0]))) + parseInt(d3.select("#chart svg .nv-bar").attr("width")))
          .attr("y2", yValueScale(limits[i][1]/ 1000000000))
          ;    
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s2vemzht/25/